# Problemas con permisos en dir : 'www' de apache al cambiar grupos. Deberia de estar funcionando

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, permisos

he decidido poner todos mis proyectos en el dir `/var/www/html/` , suelen ser proyectos de laravel y alguno de node.

Como son proyectos personales, aunque el pc sea mio, quiero hacer buenas practicas de seguridad. Habia pensado lo siguiente, todos **los proyectos que vaya subiendo** les pondre el grupo **programming** que he creado con permisos `770` es decir, solo el dueño (yo) y el grupo (programming) puede hacer algo.

Luego como esta en el directiorio de **apache** , he metido a `www-data` al grupo tambien para que pueda acceder y tal, a demas como son proyectos de laravel es necesario porque va escribiendo en los los, etc etc..

Entonces, al listar el directio : `/var/www/html` es parecido a esto :

```
.....mas proyectos con los mismo permisos.....
drwxrwx--- 14 root programming  4096 nov  5 19:04 miApp/
.....mas proyectos con los mismo permisos.....
```

Se puede ver que pertenece al user jose y esta en el grupo programming.

Verificacion de grupos :

```
$ groups www-data
www-data : www-data programming
```

Y mi usuario igual.

Entonces, desde mi user, intento acceder y me dice permiso denegado cuando hago `cd miApp`. A parte de eso, a apache no le esta dejando trabajar , indicando el siguiente error desde firefox:

```
require(/var/www/html/gua_back/bootstrap/cache/packages.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

Entonces no entiendo muy bien si le he dicho explicitamente quien puede entrar, porque no me hace caso ?

Comment: Una prueba sencilla seria hacer `sudo su - www-data` y con ese usuario tratar de ver los archivos con cat o algo así (deberías poder verlos si todo es correcto). Y en ese caso entonces probablemente es lo de la información de la sesión (sin el grupo `programmning`) que está corriendo apache. Con solo reiniciar apache, debería funcionar para que cargue lo del grupo nuevo.

Comment: me dice esto :  su www-data
This account is currently not available.

Comment: de todas formas, desde mi usuario jose no puedo acceder ni al directorio del proyecto, no es raro eso ? He reiniciado apache, he abierto una terminal nuevo y todo

Comment: intenta así: `sudo -u www-data bash`